# .NET assert assertions are enabled

Tags: c#, .net, assertion

How does one assert that assertions are enabled in C#?

[Here's a link to a related answer for Java, that does not work in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16788199/427155)

The purpose of this would be to prevent the use of release-type assemblies because where efficiency is of no concern I might as well be running with all the assertions working, so there is in some places a preference for debug-type assemblies.

Use of `Debug.Assert(false)` was not satisfactory because it creates a dialog and requires user interaction. It would be good to know assertions work without the "noise". The Java solution is noiseless.

EDIT: This is taken from a comment under the accepted answer.

```
public static class CompileTimeInformation
{
    public static void AssertAssertionsEnabled()
    {
        // Recall that assertions work only in the debug version of an assembly.
        // Thus the assertion that assertions work relies upon detecting that the assembly was compiled as a debug version.

        if (IsReleaseTypeAssembly())
            throw new ApplicationException("Assertions are not enabled.");
    }

    public static bool IsReleaseTypeAssembly()
    {
        return ! IsDebugTypeAssembly();
    }

    public static bool IsDebugTypeAssembly()
    {
        return
            #if DEBUG
                true
            #else
                false
            #endif
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean at execution time? Please give more context about what you're trying to do - assertions in Java and C# are entirely different. (Indeed, there's no such concept in the C# language itself, just a conditional method in the framework.)

Comment: Yes, at run time. Currently, I simply assert that the word "debug" is in the absolute path of the executing assembly because in a development machine, the debug-type binary has assertions enabled. This is not ideal.

Comment: But what's the bigger context here - why do you care? And why does simply asserting something that's false fail? Or are you in a different assembly? Bear in mind that different assemblies within the same app may have been compiled with different options...

Comment: I have explained more in the text of the question.

Comment: You still haven't explained whether you're interested in checking in source code in the same project/assembly as the assertions. Just `#if DEBUG` would do that...

Comment: I think ideally I'd like some assemblies to always have assertions enabled, even if they are invoked by assemblies that do not have assertions enabled. At least that would fit my current needs. I'm not sure if there's a case where I'd want all related assemblies to be "all enabled" or "all disabled". Right now a hetero setup might be good.

Comment: `#if DEBUG`. Thanks for that. Looks like a blast from the past.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Basically you can't detect whether a given *assembly* was built with a particular preprocessor symbol defined. You can only do it for the assembly you're writing code for effectively.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your questions. Example: if I have a program that is called LicenseMaker and it edits the source code for the product in a way that identifies the legitimate licensee, that LicenseMaker will only ever be run on my development machine and efficiency is not a concern so it might as well have assertions enabled, always.

Comment: What edits the source code? Again, within the same assembly you can just use `#if DEBUG` but that won't help for other assemblies.

Comment: Like the Java solution, if each assembly can fail to run if assertions are not enabled, that would be good. Silence if it is enabled is good. For my needs an assembly need not inspect other assemblies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: There's a simpler solution. The other one is still below for the curious.

```
public static bool AreAssertionsEnabled =
 #if DEBUG
  true
 #else
  false
 #endif
 ;
```

Looks nasty but is quite simple.

---

Let's first look at what causes `Debug.Assert` to disappear in non-DEBUG builds:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG"), __DynamicallyInvokable]
public static void Assert(bool condition)
{
    TraceInternal.Assert(condition);
}
```

It's `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`. That inspires the following solution:

```
public static bool AreAssertionsEnabled = false;

static MyClassName() { MaybeSetEnabled(); /* call deleted in RELEASE builds */ }

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
static void MaybeSetEnabled()
{
    AreAssertionsEnabled = true;
}
```

You can probably refactor this so that `AreAssertionsEnabled` can be `readonly`. I just can't think of a way right now.

You can now check the boolean value `AreAssertionsEnabled` and perform any logic you like based on it.

Comment: To make it `readonly`, you could either use `#if DEBUG` (same behavior as `ConditionalAttribute` as long as you're in the same assembly), or make the `AreAssertionsEnabled` field private, then copy its value to a different `public static readonly` field if the constructor after the `MaybeSetEnabled()` call.

Comment: I would point out that this C# solution has to be source code cut-and-pasted for re-use. The Java solution can be in a library for re-use.

Comment: `internal static class AssertionsEnabledAsserter
    {
        internal static void Assert()
        {
            if (!IsDebugTypeAssembly())
                throw new ApplicationException("Assertions are not enabled.");
        }

        private static bool IsDebugTypeAssembly()
        {
            return
#if DEBUG
 true
#else
 false
#endif
;
        }
    }` That's what I decided to cut-and-paste.

Comment: @H2ONaCl that is true. Debug mode is not a property of the .NET runtime. It is a language/compiler concept. Even a framework concept: ASP.NET has a runtime-detectable debug mode.

Comment: Eventually I decided that since I have no need for mixing debug assemblies and release assemblies, a single instance of that code in a library was sufficient. If the library says assertions are enabled then it is a debug assembly and therefore all other assemblies are also debug assemblies. In other words, I didn't need to have duplicates of that code for each assembly.